# is any browser implemented NAT traversal?

Tags: javascript, nat, webrtc

Is there any browser implement NAT traversal? I need NAT traversal to establish the peer connection between the browsers.How can i establish peer connection using NAT, for working NAT traversal should i install something like ICE framework?.

Answer (score 0):

The browsers that are implementing WebRTC already have a built-in mechanism of NAT-T using STUN/TURN servers and using ICE to establish sessions. Chrome and Firefox are two of the browsers that have this mechnisms implemented and you [can use WebRTC API's](http://www.webrtc.org/) to create and configure a PeerConnection, that will handle them.